# Android+Phonegap: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-mediaplayer

I am getting this error in LogCat.

The same web app code is working on iOS but I am getting this Error on Android

```
Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
```

Thank You.

Comment: It tell your everything, your player is valid in iOS but not in Android. You must change MediaPlayer and can you give us some code?

Comment: Im using phonegap. I think phonegap is calling getDuration before the track is loaded. But i dont no how can i change this.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: You have to call getDuration() only when your player is prepared. This is, inside onPrepared() callback of your MediaPlayer onPreparedListener

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable `mIsPreparedForPlayback` and set it on prepared:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

//...

public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer player) {
    mIsPreparedForPlayback = true;
}
```

then you check that before trying to get it.